# Difference Ga'al and Natzal

Tags: words, passover-seder-hagada, va-eira

shemot 6:6-7 reads the famous quote for the Pesach cups.
But what's the actual difference between deliver (natzal) and redeem (ga'al)?

take away from a problem? and remove the problem?

Please help me out here ?

Comment: How about padah and hoshia?

Comment: The Maharal discusses the 4 expressions as removing 4 different levels.. It's in his haggada - don't have it to hand, sorry.

Comment: It's 'Hitzil', not 'Natzal'.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot the OP is right. The Shoresh is נ.צ.ל. In Hifil forms, the Nun drops and there is a Dagesh Chazak in the Ayin-HaPoal. Consider how Nafal conjugates to Hippil.

Answer (score 2):

[Sforno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Jacob_Sforno) provides an explination between the two languages:

(*Sources provided from [Sefaria.org](http://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> **והצלתי:** ביום צאתכם שתצאו מגבולם
>
> **And I will rescue you:** *On the day you leave out from their (the Egyptian's) border*
>
> **וגאלתי:** בטביעת המצרים בים, כמו שהעיד באמרו ויושע ה' ביום ההוא וכו', כי אחרי מות המשעבדים לא היו עוד עבדים בורחים
>
> **And I will redeem you:** *With drowning the Egyptians by the sea (of reeds), like they (the Jewish people) testified and said "and G-d saved on that day etc." for after their (the Egyptian's) death they were no longer fleeing as slaves*

The [Ramban](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.6?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) and the [Ohr HaChayim HaKadosh](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.6?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=en) offer explanations as well in similar veins.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch to the cited verse explains that

> Whereas הציל denotes rescue from impending danger, גאל denotes redemption from a process of destruction that has already begun.